# How to fix Azure functions "inotify limit" error

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

I am trying to run a durable entity that I had described originally in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70806712/out-of-proc-orchestrators-must-return-a-valid-json-schema-error-while-executin) question. While trying to figure out that issue I have started getting the below error after a few runs.

```
The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
```

Below is the full log of the error. Can someone point me to the possible cause and fix?

```
user:func1$ func start -p 8080
Found Python version 3.6.9 (python3).

Azure Functions Core Tools
Core Tools Version:       4.0.3971 Commit hash: d0775d487c93ebd49e9c1166d5c3c01f3c76eaaf  (64-bit)
Function Runtime Version: 4.0.1.16815


Functions:

        Entityfn: entityTrigger

        KWhCalculator: activityTrigger

        Orch: orchestrationTrigger

        Starter: eventHubTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:44825/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream application/grpc -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
[2022-01-24T10:58:42.582Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2022-01-24T10:58:47.753Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A845906C'.
[2022-01-24T10:58:47.833Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '9803b89f-6cf1-4fe1-a482-075e770a9fea'.
[2022-01-24T10:58:47.833Z] System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:44825/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream application/grpc - - 200 - application/grpc 5879.0529ms
info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[14]
      Error reading message.
      System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.
       ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.DefaultPipeReader.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadStreamMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HMEV51U1VS7R", Request id "0HMEV51U1VS7R:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:44825/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream application/grpc -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
[2022-01-24T10:58:49.902Z] Worker process started and initialized.
[2022-01-24T10:58:55.521Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000A845906C'.
[2022-01-24T10:58:55.578Z] A host error has occurred during startup operation '3b77fea3-afd0-427c-9d79-3175d7f0b815'.
[2022-01-24T10:58:55.578Z] System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher: The configured user limit (128) on the number of inotify instances has been reached, or the per-process limit on the number of open file descriptors has been reached.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[1]
      Executed endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
info: Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.ServerCallHandler[14]
      Error reading message.
      System.IO.IOException: The request stream was aborted.
       ---> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Connections.ConnectionAbortedException: The HTTP/2 connection faulted.
         --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadResult(ReadResult& result)
         at System.IO.Pipelines.Pipe.GetReadAsyncResult()
         at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http2.Http2MessageBody.ReadAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.PoolingAsyncValueTaskMethodBuilder`1.StateMachineBox`1.System.Threading.Tasks.Sources.IValueTaskSource<TResult>.GetResult(Int16 token)
         at Grpc.AspNetCore.Server.Internal.PipeExtensions.ReadStreamMessageAsync[T](PipeReader input, HttpContextServerCallContext serverCallContext, Func`2 deserializer, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[2]
      Request finished HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:44825/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream application/grpc - - 200 - application/grpc 6153.6504ms
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel[32]
      Connection id "0HMEV51U1VS7S", Request id "0HMEV51U1VS7S:00000001": the application completed without reading the entire request body.
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Diagnostics[1]
      Request starting HTTP/2 POST http://127.0.0.1:44825/AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream application/grpc -
info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware[0]
      Executing endpoint 'gRPC - /AzureFunctionsRpcMessages.FunctionRpc/EventStream'
```

Answer (score 0):

Restarting VS Code and creating a new Azure Function project did not help.

Fix: I restarted my system and the error is gone.

Cause: Not sure, but looks like long time running locally with long JSON messages might have opened lot of listeners on the port